# Displaying an alert on a new View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uialertcontroller

I have a button that sends me on another View Controller. What I am trying is to display an alert on the next View Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `viewDidLoad()` method of the new controller, create a new `UIAlertController` and display it like the following

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default Style", message: "A standard alert.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
    // ...
}
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
    // ...
}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that this example was taken from the NSHipster website which offers nice articles about iOS. You can find the article about UIAlertController [here](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/). They also explain other stuff you can do with that class, like display an Action Sheet for example.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

Create an `extension` of `UIViewController` with your function to display alert with required parameter arguments

```
extension UIViewController {

      func displayalert(title:String, message:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        })))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


      }
}
```

Now call this function from your view controller:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.displayalert(title: <String>, message: <String>)
    }
}
```